# Swap uniqueness-validated values with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a model defined like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :bar
end
```

And a service that performs a certain operation on them:

```
class FooService
  class << self
    def run(bars_by_foo_id)
      foos = Foo.find(bars_by_foo_id.keys).index_by(&:id)
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        bars_by_foo_id.each do |foo_id, bar|
          foo = foos[foo_id]
          foo.bar = bar
          foo.save!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try this:

```
# Works
FooService.run({ 1: "a", 2: "b" })
# Breaks
FooService.run({ 1: "b", 2: "a" })
```

The first call to `.run` assigns the correct `bar` to each `Foo`, but the second one breaks, obviously, because when trying to assign `"b"` to the first `Foo`, this value is not unique anymore.

I tried:

```
def run(bars_by_foo_id)
  Foo.update(
    bars_by_foo_id.keys,
    bars_by_foo_id.values.map do |bar|
      { bar: bar }
    end
  )
end
```

But apparently this only makes several individual updates and still breaks.

What would be the correct way to achieve this? Can I make this in a single SQL statement? I don't have a unique constraint in my database, only in my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least ugly way I have been able to come up with is this:

```
def run(bars_by_foo_id)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_update(bars_by_foo_id))
    foos = Foo.find(bars_by_foo_id.keys)
    foos.each(&:validate!)
  end
end

private

def sql_update(bars_by_foo_id)
  <<-SQL
    UPDATE foos SET
      bar = bars_by_foo_id.bar
    FROM (VALUES
      #{update_values(bars_by_foo_id)}
    ) AS bars_by_foo_id(id, bar)
    WHERE bars_by_foo_id.id = foos.id;
  SQL
end

def update_values(bars_by_foo_id)
  bars_by_foo_id.map do |id, bar|
    "(#{id}, #{bar})"
  end.join(",")
end
```